# How can I control the execution and the cancelation of an interval on a button's click?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to change the background color of my HTML page, every 200 milliseconds using setInterval in the event of a click on the button id = 'button4'. And I want the changing of background color to stop when the user clicks on the same button again.

The code for setInterval is executed when assigned to var x whereas I want to execute it when a condition is satisfied inside the 'goCrazy' function when it is called. How can that be done?

The clearInterval is working fine and the changing of colors is stopped.

Below is my code.

```
var x = setInterval(() => {
    const rndInt1 = randomIntFromInterval(0, 255);
    const rndInt2 = randomIntFromInterval(0, 255);
    const rndInt3 = randomIntFromInterval(0, 255);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${rndInt1}, ${rndInt2}, ${rndInt3})`;
}, 200);

function goCrazy() {

    if (document.getElementById('button4').innerText == 'Go Crazy') {
        document.getElementById('button4').innerText = 'stop';
        x;
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById('button4').innerText = 'Go Crazy';
    }
}


function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
```

Comment: you may have your setInterval callback running in background and checking for the value of a global boolean that you'll flip with the button click. there are surely similar questions here already

Comment: _"The code for setInterval is executing as soon as I am assigning it to the var x"_ - well that is what happens when you _call_ a function, the code inside of it will execute.

Comment: @DiegoD No global is necessary and they should *never* be used unless absolutely necessary

Comment: `x;` - this doesn't do anything. The return value of `setInterval` is an interval ID. Writing `5;` instead would have the exact same non-effect.

Comment: @CBroe I know the code is already wrong, and that functions execute at the time of assigning, what I am looking for is a way to call setInterval at a later time in the same code.

Comment: Then wrap it into an anonymous function, and assign that to a variable ...?

Comment: @CBroe wrapping it in anonymous function and assigning it to x is working fine at the time of calling. But I am unable to get the id to provide for clear Interval

Comment: Well where did you get the ID from to begin with? It was the result of the `setInterval` call. So you need to return that "upwards" from within your anonymous function, and then do `let myInterval = x();` or something.

Comment: @Fakipo ... The detection of a running/halted interval via comparing the button's text content is not very reliable.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I agree, it is just a demo project. But its better to have proper coding practices. How would you suggest that one should go on about in such cases?

Comment: @Fakipo ... see my answer which utilizes a bindable event handler function for any kind of state handling. There the running/halted state of the background changing interval for instance gets detected via the current value of a bound `timerId`. The handler function is re-usable and configurable for it supports different toggle-button texts as well.

Comment: "The code for setInterval is executes when assigned to var x where as I want to execute it when a condition is satisfied inside the 'goCrazy' function when it is called." - what's wrong with, er, **putting the code that should execute when the condition is satisfied, inside the condition**?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel if I put the code inside the condition, then I wont be able to clear interval as the id would go out of scope for the else condition

Comment: The id is just an ID. It's a **result of calling** the function. That can be assigned to a variable with a wider scope, from code that is inside the condition. That's the fundamental thing the answers you've gotten so far have in common. Was that the point of confusion?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, I wasnt able to figure out that logic, I was instead trying to bind the setinterval and do something with that bound function.

Comment: Ah. It probably would have been better to show the other attempt and ask about the other problem, then.

Comment: @Fakipo ... The OP might check on the latest edit of my provided answer. The 2nd approach changes from a `this`-context aware (thus explicitly to be bound) event-handler to a `this`-context-free [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). Btw both approaches are perfectly fine "idiomatic JavaScript". Both example codes are provided as executable stack snippets, thus both prove what each of their description claims it is doing. It is on the OP to choose with which one to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the code inside `setInterval` into a named function, and call `setInterval` or `clearInterval` within `goCrazy`.

```js
var x;

function goCrazy(){
    if (document.getElementById('button4').innerText == 'Go Crazy') {
        document.getElementById('button4').innerText = 'stop';
        x = setInterval(changeBackground, 200);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('button4').innerText = 'Go Crazy';
        if (x) clearInterval(x);
    } 
}

function changeBackground() {
    const rndInt1 = randomIntFromInterval(0, 255);
    const rndInt2 = randomIntFromInterval(0, 255);
    const rndInt3 = randomIntFromInterval(0, 255);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${rndInt1}, ${rndInt2}, ${rndInt3})`;
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
```

Comment: This is working correctly. It is not necessary to use a named function, we can use an anonymous function as well. The correct part is taking a global undefined variable, then assigning it the id of setInterval and using the same id (if exists) to clear the interval. Marking it as correct.

Comment: @Dexygen I agree, it is better to not use global variables if possible. I was thinking of writing an answer using closures to wrap `x` inside the `goCrazy` function, but without the HTML code to test it out, I think I'll pass.

Answer (score -2):

The OP firstly needs to make the background changing function that is to be executed within an interval an addressable function by e.g. implementing it as [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).

Second, the OP needs to keep track of a running/halted interval. One could achieve this by a single event handler which is aware of an own `this` context where one could [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) at least a `timeId` to it and maybe even some additional button-related text-data.

The implementation of the handler function which gets registered with a button's `'click'` [event-listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) then is very straightforward.

Depending on the `null` value comparison of the bound `timerId` one detects an either `'running'` or `'halted'` interval which makes it easy to continue with either clearing the running interval or starting a new interval (including the button's text-toggle).

```js
function getRandomValue(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
function setRandomBackgroundColor() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor =
    `rgb(${getRandomValue(0, 255)},${getRandomValue(0, 255)},${getRandomValue(0, 255)})`;
}

function toggleBackgroundBehaviorFromBoundState({ currentTarget: elmBtn }) {
  let toggleState;

  if ((this.timerId ?? null) !== null) {

    clearInterval(this.timerId);

    // explicitly nullify value due to the above `null` comparison.
    this.timerId = null;

    toggleState = 'halted';
  } else {
    this.timerId = setInterval(setRandomBackgroundColor, 100);

    toggleState = 'running';
  }
  elmBtn.textContent = this?.buttonCopy?.[toggleState];
}

function main() {
  document
    .querySelector('#button4')
    .addEventListener(
      'click',
      toggleBackgroundBehaviorFromBoundState.bind({
        buttonCopy: {
          running: 'Stop',
          halted: 'Go Crazy',
        },
        timerId: null,
      })
    );
}
main();
```

```html
<button id="button4">Go Crazy</button>
```

***Edit***

Since the above solution has been referred to as *"confusing and non-idiomatic JavaScript"*, the very one is taken and adapted to the seemingly to be favored `this`-context-free [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)-style.

```js
function getRandomValue(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
function setRandomBackgroundColor() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor =
    `rgb(${getRandomValue(0, 255)},${getRandomValue(0, 255)},${getRandomValue(0, 255)})`;
}

function enableBackgroundToggleForButton(elmBtn, btnCopy = {}) {
  function toggleBackgroundBehavior() {
    let toggleCopy;

    if (timerId !== null) {

      clearInterval(timerId);

      timerId = null;
      toggleCopy = copyHalted;
    } else {
      timerId = setInterval(setRandomBackgroundColor, 100);
      toggleCopy = copyRunning;
    }
    elmBtn.textContent = toggleCopy;
  }
  // explicitly nullify value due to the above `null` comparison.
  let timerId = null;
  const {
    halted: copyHalted,
    running: copyRunning,
  } = btnCopy;

  elmBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleBackgroundBehavior);
}

enableBackgroundToggleForButton(
  document.querySelector('#button4'),
  { halted: 'Go Crazy', running: 'Stop'},
);
```

```html
<button id="button4">Go Crazy</button>
```